# Problem with JSON in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer-7, undefined

IE8/Chrome,FF work well but Internet Explorer 7 is giving me headaches.

I am trying to get numeric result for actual form

```
$(".checklist label").click(function () {
    checkResults();
});

function checkResults() {
    var str = $("form").serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/data.asmx/GetTotal",
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ data: str }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: handleHtml,
        error: ajaxFailed
    });
}

function handleHtml(msg) {
    $("#result").text(msg.d);
}

function ajaxFailed(xmlRequest) {
}
```

What have I done wrong that IE7 wont work?

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

JSON.stringify is not part of IE7.

You'll have to use Douglas Crockford's JavaScript implementation of this:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

More specifically this script:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

It will add the stringify and parse methods to browser that do not natively implement this (like IE7 and below)

Comment: BTW you don't have to use json stringify, as data parameter in $.ajax you can use whole object.

Comment: thanks this answer helped me ... +1 for helpful answer and -1 for IE .

Comment: @MarrLiss Do you mean in IE7 we don't need to do Stringify? I am not able to get it working (without any file added)

Comment: @Izkata doesn't work for me. .NET webservice fails on deserialization. It needs { ... data: {"data":"value"}, ...} but it fails if value is stored in other then string type property. JSON.stringify solves that nicely.

Comment: i recieve error `script does not support assembly` in IE 7